# How to retrieve all fields from database in yii framework

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

i'm implementing line chart in my application using flot extension. I'm fetching one value  and a plot graph. I'm fetching one field like this....

```
foreach ($model->getGraphData()->getData() as $row) {

    $data[]=array($row['id'],$row['height']);

}
```

I've weight, height, chest, hips, biceps fields in my database. Can i know how to retrieve all fields in one variabl $data[].

And my model part is...

```
public function getGraphData()
{
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    //$criteria->addCondition('CreatedDate > datetime(\'now\', \'-1 day\', \'localtime\')');

    $sort = new CSort();
    $sort->defaultOrder='updatedDate';

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
            'sort'=>$sort,
            'pagination'=>false,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want something like array_value() to be used with $row ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
foreach ($model->getGraphData()->getData(true) as $row) { ...
```

Set 'true' as parameter in 'getData()' method.

Comment: Actually i'm getting only one field.

 `$data[]=array($row['id'],$row['height']);`
If i give weight instead of height its plotting weight values..So, can i know how to provide all fields here..

Comment: in $row now you have a object with all attributes, then try this:

foreach ($model->getGraphData()->getData(true) as $row) {

    $data[]=$row;

}